# Rotate an image with trigonometry

Tags: java, math, rotation, trigonometry, angle

i would like to rotate an image like the next gif:
[rotation that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4SGZ.gif)

but i'm getting this result:

[wrong rotation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojZcrgXKzPY&ab_channel=Cupa)

```
public int[] rotateByAngle(int posx, int posz, double angle){
    double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double cos = Math.cos(radians);
    double sin = Math.sin(radians);



    int rotate_x  = (int) Math.floor((posx * cos - posz * sin)) ;
    int rotate_z  = (int) Math.floor((posx * sin  + posz * cos)) ;


    return new int[] {rotate_x ,rotate_z };
}
```

```
public void drawImage(MapCanvas canvas,int x, int y, BufferedImage image,double angle) {
    byte[] bytes = MapPalette.imageToBytes(image);

    for(int x2 = 0; x2 < image.getWidth(); ++x2) {
        for(int y2 = 0; y2 < image.getHeight(); ++y2) {
            byte c =  bytes[y2 * image.getWidth() + x2];
            if(c == 0) continue;
            int [] sol = rotateByAngle(x2,y2,angle);
            canvas.setPixel(x + sol[0], y + sol[1],c);
        }
    }

}
```

```
drawImage(canvas,64,64, img.getBufferedImage(),angle);
```

i dont want to use => AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
i would like to use cos and sen

Comment: One improvement, round, not floor.  `rotate_x  = (int) Math.round((posx * cos - posz * sin))`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void drawImage(MapCanvas canvas,int x, int y, BufferedImage image,double angle) {
    byte[] bytes = MapPalette.imageToBytes(image);

    int real_x = image.getWidth()/2;
    int real_y = image.getHeight()/2;

    for(int x2 = 0; x2 < image.getWidth(); ++x2) {
        for(int y2 = 0; y2 < image.getHeight(); ++y2) {

            byte c =  bytes[y2 * image.getWidth() + x2];
            if(c == 0) continue;
            int [] sol = rotateByAngle(x2-real_x,y2-real_y,angle);
            canvas.setPixel(x + sol[0], y + sol[1],c);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your answer! Please consider including some brief explanation about your answer instead of posting only code.